# ArrayList remove function has bug?

Tags: android, arraylist

This is my code

```
  public void onClick(View view){
            Logger.debug(TAG, view.getId()+"-->ID");
            ImageView img = (ImageView)hasID.get(view.getId());
            ImageView sameple = (ImageView)hasID.get(isample);

        Logger.debug(TAG, "----------------------");
        Logger.debug(TAG, listFruit.size()+"--->list size");
        Logger.debug(TAG, img.getId() + "--->id");
        Logger.debug(TAG, sameple.getId() +"--->sample id");
        Logger.debug(TAG, hasName.get(img.getId()) +"--->name");
        Logger.debug(TAG, hasName.get(sameple.getId())+ "---> sample name");
        Logger.debug(TAG, "----------------------");
        if(view.getId() == isample){
            String oldScore = this.score.getText().toString();
            int newscore = Integer.valueOf(oldScore) + 1;
            this.score.setText(String.valueOf(newscore));
            boolean b = listFruit.remove(sameple);
            Logger.debug(TAG, "result:"+b);
            scorrect.start();
            change_number_click(0);
            img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            randomSample();
        }else{//click wrong
            swrong.start();
        }
    }

public void randomSample(){
    isample = random.nextInt(listFruit.size());
    for(int i = 0;i<listFruit.size();i++){
        int id = getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(fruit.get(i).file, "drawable",
                getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
        Logger.debug(TAG, hasName.get(id)+"-->name");
    }
    Logger.debug(TAG, "------create sample------");
    Logger.debug(TAG, listFruit.size()+"-->list size");
    Logger.debug(TAG, isample+"-->sample");
    int id = getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(fruit.get(isample).file, "drawable",
            getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
    Logger.debug(TAG, id +"-->id sample");
    Logger.debug(TAG, hasName.get(id)+"-->name");
    this.sample.setImageResource(id);
    this.sample.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    isample = id;
    Logger.debug(TAG, "-------------------------");
}
```

And this is result on console:

```
07-20 02:33:50.694    annona-->name
07-20 02:33:50.694    apple-->name
07-20 02:33:50.694    banana-->name
07-20 02:33:50.694    ------create sample------
07-20 02:33:50.694    3-->list size
07-20 02:33:50.694    0-->sample
07-20 02:33:50.694    2130837563-->id sample
07-20 02:33:50.694    annona-->name
07-20 02:33:50.694    -------------------------
07-20 02:33:50.694    2130837563-->sample
07-20 02:33:50.786    Tick...
07-20 02:33:51.794    Tick...
07-20 02:33:52.694    2130837563-->ID
07-20 02:33:52.694    ----------------------
07-20 02:33:52.694    3--->list size
07-20 02:33:52.694    2130837563--->id
07-20 02:33:52.694    2130837563--->sample id
07-20 02:33:52.694    annona--->name
07-20 02:33:52.694    annona---> sample name
07-20 02:33:52.694    ----------------------
07-20 02:33:52.694    result:true
07-20 02:33:52.698    annona-->name
07-20 02:33:52.698    apple-->name
07-20 02:33:52.698    ------create sample------
07-20 02:33:52.698    2-->list size
07-20 02:33:52.698    0-->sample
07-20 02:33:52.698    2130837563-->id sample
07-20 02:33:52.698    annona-->name
07-20 02:33:52.698    -------------------------
```

As you see. listFruit is Arraylist

```
List<ImageView> listFruit = new ArrayList<>();
```

and this is list value

```
07-20 02:33:50.694    annona-->name
07-20 02:33:50.694    apple-->name
07-20 02:33:50.694    banana-->name
```

First, it creates a sample object

```
07-20 02:33:50.694    ------create sample------
07-20 02:33:50.694    3-->list size
07-20 02:33:50.694    0-->sample
07-20 02:33:50.694    2130837563-->id sample
07-20 02:33:50.694    annona-->name
```

is **annona**, in **onClick** function I remove if user click on sample object

```
//hasID is hashtable, with key is id, and value is object in listFruit
ImageView sameple = (ImageView)hasID.get(isample);
```

it return **true**
But I see it always remove last item in listFruit ArrayList

```
07-20 02:33:52.694    result:true
07-20 02:33:52.698    annona-->name
07-20 02:33:52.698    apple-->name
```

Actually, It must remove annona at first item, but not. What's wrong?

**More information***

I changed my code to this

```
  Logger.debug(TAG, "----------------\n");
                Logger.debug(TAG, "Before remove:");
                for(int i = 0;i<listFruit.size();i++){
                    int id = getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(fruit.get(i).file, "drawable",
                            getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
                    Logger.debug(TAG, hasName.get(id)+"-->name");
                }
                Logger.debug(TAG, "remove ID:"+ksample);
                listFruit.remove(ksample);
                Logger.debug(TAG, "After remove:");
                for(int i = 0;i<listFruit.size();i++){
                    int id = getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(fruit.get(i).file, "drawable",
                            getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
                    Logger.debug(TAG, hasName.get(id)+"-->name");
                }
                Logger.debug(TAG,"------------------\n");
```

I remove by **index**, and this is result:

```
07-20 03:05:59.694     Before remove:
07-20 03:05:59.694     annona-->name
07-20 03:05:59.694     apple-->name
07-20 03:05:59.694     remove ID:0
07-20 03:05:59.694     After remove:
07-20 03:05:59.694     annona-->name
```

I removed at position **0 - annona** but it still remove last item :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you print out the contents of your list with this code you are reading from the `fruit` list rather than the `listFruit` list, you only use `listFruit` to get the size.

```
for(int i = 0;i<listFruit.size();i++){
        int id = getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(fruit.get(i).file, "drawable",
                getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
        Logger.debug(TAG, hasName.get(id)+"-->name");
    }
```

Since you don't remove any item from `fruit` then it doesn't change, so when you print it out it just prints out one less item (because `listFruit` is now one item smaller).

To fix this issue you need to ensure that the items in `fruit` are in the same order as `listFruit`, and remove an item from `fruit` at the same time you remove an item from `listFruit`.

Comment: oh, it's my stupid mistake, I get me hours headache to find out where is wrong.